# Prove $\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\left[\frac1{t^2}-\frac1{(1-e^{-t})^2}+\frac1{1-e^{-t}}-\frac1{12}\right]dt=\frac34-\zeta'(-1)+\zeta'(0)$

Tags: integration, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

How to prove
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\left[\frac1{t^2}-\frac1{(1-e^{-t})^2}+\frac1{1-e^{-t}}-\frac1{12}\right]dt=\frac34-\zeta'(-1)+\zeta'(0)$$
?

This integral appeared in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519342/finding-the-leading-order-contribution-to-a-certain-integral/3524179#3524179), and according to an arXiv paper and the OP's conjecture this equality is very likely to be true. This is also supported by numerical evidence.

You cannot find the integral in the arXiv paper, as the integral arises in my lengthy proof of a statement (whose proof is omitted) in the paper. Thus I think it is not very useful to provide the link.

Real or complex approaches are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually it would be VERY useful (and interesting, maybe) to provide links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will first evaluate $$I(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{s-1}e^{-t} \left(\frac{1}{t^{2}} - \frac{1}{(1-e^{-t})^{2}} + \frac{1}{1-e^{-t}} - \frac{1}{12} \right) \, \mathrm dt \tag{1}$$ for $\Re(s)>2$.

With the restriction $\Re(s)>2$, we can break up the integral into four convergent integrals and evaluate each integral separately.

The first integral is just $\Gamma(s-2)$, the third integral is $\Gamma(s) \zeta(s)$, and the fourth integral is $\frac{1}{12} \, \Gamma(s)$.

The second integral is $\Gamma(s) \zeta(s-1)$, which as **Szeto** stated in comments below can be derived by preforming integration by parts on the representation $$\Gamma(s) \zeta(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1} e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}} \, \mathrm dt.$$

Combing all 4 integrals, we get   $$I(s) = \left(\Gamma(s-2) -\Gamma(s) \zeta(s-1) + \Gamma(s)\zeta(s) - \frac{1}{12} \,\Gamma(s)\right) \tag{2}$$ for $\Re(s) >2 $.

The Mellin transform, like the Laplace transform, defines an analytic function where the integral converges absolutely. Since integral $(1)$ behaves like a constant times $t^{s+1}$ near $t=0$, the integral defines an analytic function for $\Re(s)>−2$.

And expression $(2)$ is also an analytic function for  $\Re(s) >-2$ if we assign it its limit values at $s=2$,$1$,$0$, and $-1$.

It then follows from the identity theorem that $$I(s) =\left(\Gamma(s-2) -\Gamma(s) \zeta(s-1) + \Gamma(s)\zeta(s) - \frac{1}{12} \,\Gamma(s)\right) $$ for $\operatorname{Re}(s) >-2$.

To find $I(0)$, we'll expand the terms in Laurent series at $s=0$.

The gamma function has simple poles at zero and the negative integers with residue $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}$.

So at $s=-2$, $\Gamma(s) = \frac{1}{2(s+2)} + \mathcal{O}(1)$.

The constant term of the Laurent series of $\Gamma(s)$ at $s=-2$ is then $$ \begin{align} \lim_{s \to -2} \left(\Gamma(s) - \frac{1}{2(s+2)} \right) &= \lim_{s \to -2} \left(\frac{\Gamma(s+3)}{s(s+1)(s+2)} - \frac{1}{2(s+2)}\right) \\ &= \lim_{s \to -2} \frac{2 \Gamma(s+3)-s(s+1)}{2s(s+1)(s+2)} \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{ s \to -2} \frac{2 \Gamma'(s+3)-2s-1}{(s+1)(s+2)+s(s+2)+s(s+1)}\\  &= \frac{2\Gamma'(1)+3}{4}. \end{align}$$

Since the Laurent series of $\Gamma(s)$ at $s=-2$ has the same coefficients as the Laurent series of $\Gamma(s-2)$ at $s=0$, we get $$ \Gamma(s-2) = \frac{1}{2s} +\frac{\Gamma'(1)}{2} + \frac{3}{4} + \mathcal{O}(s).$$

Similarly, $$\Gamma(s) =  \frac{1}{s} + \Gamma'(1) + \mathcal{O}(s).$$

Therefore, $$\begin{align} I(0) = \small \lim_{s \to 0} \Big[\frac{1}{2s} &+ \small  \frac{\Gamma'(1)}{2} + \frac{3}{4} + \mathcal{O}(s) - \left(\frac{1}{s} + \Gamma'(1) + \mathcal{O}(s) \right) \left(\zeta(-1) - \zeta(0) + \zeta'(-1)s - \zeta'(0)s+ \mathcal{O}(s^{2}) \right) \\ &- \small \frac{1}{12} \left(\frac{1}{s} + \Gamma'(1) + \mathcal{O}(s) \right)\Big] \end{align} $$

where $\zeta(0) = - \frac{1}{2}$ and $\zeta(-1) = -\frac{1}{12}$.

This results in mass cancellation, and we end up with $$I(0) = \lim_{ s \to 0} \left( \frac{3}{4} - \zeta'(1) + \zeta'(0) + \mathcal{O}(s)\right) = \frac{3}{4} - \zeta'(1)  +\zeta'(0). $$

Comment: $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s-1)$ can be derived by performing integration by parts on the Mellin transform integral representation of $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @Szeto Indeed you can evaluate that integral by simply using integration by parts. Good observation.

Comment: Actually it is a very good answer. However, I think you missed one point: you did not justify why you can take $s\to 0$ on an expression obtained by assuming $s>2$. Here is the justification: Let $i(s)=\Gamma(s-2)-\Gamma(s)\zeta(s-1)+\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)+\frac1{12}\Gamma(s)$.  $I(s)$ converges and is analytic for $s>-1$; $I(s)$ and $i(s)$ coincide for $s>2$. Since $i(s)$ can be analytically continued to $s>-1$ easily, we are sure that $I(s)$ and $i(s)$ also coincide on $s>-1$ by identity theorem. Therefore, it is justified to take the limit $s\to 0$ on $i(s)$ to evaluate $I(0)$.

Comment: Moreover, taking $s\to 0^+$ is unnecessary; $s\to 0$ also works. Also, there is a sign error on the last line.

Comment: @Szeto It appears that the integral should actually converge for $s>-2$ since the integrand behaves like $t^{s+1}$ near $t=0$.  But taking a right-sided limit was definitely unnecessary.